# Devise before_filter on the whole controller except results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I haven't tried this yet however i'm looking to restrict users to only see one of the methods. Whilst the other two require you to be logged in.

Heres how it currently stands

```
  def index
    # @newevents = Newevent.all
    @newevents = Newevent.order("eventname").page(params[:page]).per(25)
  end

  def create
    create_params = params[:newevent].permit(:eventname, :eventshortdesc, :eventvenuename, :eventdesc, :eventdate, :eventtime, :eventimage,)
    @newevent = Newevent.new(create_params)
    @newevent.save!
  end

  def search
    @events = Newevent.search params[:search], partial: true, misspellings: {distance: 4}
    if @events.results.any?
    render 'event/results'
  else
    render 'pages/home'
  end
  end
```

Now im only wanting the search to be accessible via everyone, Whilst the index and create are accessible to people who are logged into the website.

Thanks for any help

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood what you want, it could be done like that

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: :search
```

Comment: Mines on a before filter, Does it matter?

Comment: Doesn't matter, it's just a different syntax.